# find roc/auc/auc-roc score for single class 1's in y_true variable

Tags: python-3.x, metrics, evaluation, auc, false-positive

How to calculate auc or roc or auc-roc score from `y_true` and `y_pred` values for **SINGLE CLASS** in `y_true` using python code.

I have checked various similar questions on stackoverflow and internet but the task is not solved or the output is not that is expected.

Here is example of `y_true` and `y_pred` values.

```
y_true = numpy.array([1,1,1])

y_pred = numpy.array([0.36,0.82,0.46])
```

Or,

```
y_true = [1,1,1]

y_pred = [0.36,0.82,0.46]
```

As a mention, I have checked with various built-in functions of python libraries and found that although the true-positive-rate can be found but the false-positive-rate is shown as nan or not a number.

tensorflow and/or theano and/or pytorch and/or caffe and/or sklearn and/or other python libraries or modified function of python can be used to find **AUC or ROC or AUC-ROC score** value from **y_true of single class value 1's** and y_pred predicted scores.

Please comment if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will read about how roc auc works (https://medium.com/@penggongting/understanding-roc-auc-pros-and-cons-why-is-bier-score-a-great-supplement-c7a0c976b679 or https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/roc-and-auc) you will understand, that roc auc it's not about scoring, it's about sorting. And there is answer on your question: if you try to calculate a class with one value, how can you sort it? - nohow, you can't sort it. That's why you can't calculate it.